# Issue Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA

Tags: linux, tensorflow, qsub

I met this issue when I running my python file in linux.
I searched some answers in google like use the code below:

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

The system can be running but without ant out information. Actually I found the 2 measn ignore all information while 1 means give all information like error or normal output.

because I need to use GPU so my original code is:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
```

But if I keep the code my output would be an error information like the title.
How can I do? and of course I need use the GPU and the codes can be running in colab which indicated that my code has no problem.

some guys even said uninstall tensorboard...that must a wrong way.

Or should I download tensorflow gpu not tensorflow in m,y virtual enviroment? when I USE THE tensorflow gpu version, the error is core dumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If when forcing the `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"` doesn't work, then this means that your tensorflow gpu installation did not succeed. You must ensure you have the right combination of `TensorFlow` + `CUDA` + `CUDNN`. That is why you get the error, because due to improper versions/installation TF falls back on CPU.

Comment: So I have to use tensorflow gpu not tensorflow if I want to use the code : os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0" right?

Comment: if my anaconda has tensorflow gpu and tensorflow. it won't be a problem, right? or shoule I uninstall tensorflow?

Comment: As of TF 2.1, the GPU is by default in tensorflow package

Comment: What versions of TF. CUDA and CUDNN do you use?

Comment: tf 2.2.0 python 3.7.7

Comment: as for cuda, I don't know why I input nvidia smi ,the output is without any command

Comment: then my 2.2.0 must default in tensorflow package

Comment: and now I met the memory error. so sad. I don't know why.

Comment: You should start by reinstalling the graphics driver in Ubuntu. Ensure that works before you move on

Comment: Did you manage to get your problem solved? Since you accepted my answer, could you also upvote it so that it helps both me and other users? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. I think that's not an error output. when I use torch the issue disappeared.

Comment: The message is indeed a warning one -> it can appear when you force CPU usage (GPU could also work) but also when GPU is not found as a fallback procedure.

Comment: how to upvote your answer, sir

Comment: Click on the upper triangle on my answer (that is the upvote)

Comment: I have clicked it ,that triangle symbol, right?

Comment: Yes, it is that triangle